# "Subtracting" Ordinals - possible?

Tags: ordinals

I was wondering whether it is possible to "subtract" ordinals, or in other words -
does there exist an ordinal $\gamma$ for every pair of infinite ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$ or $\gamma+\alpha=\beta$...

Any ideas?

Comment: I am sure of this: if $\alpha<\beta$ then there is a unique $\gamma$ with $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$. I encountered it as an exercise in a good book about sets. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with the stuff to provide a proof of it. I suspect that $\gamma$ is the type of the well-ordening on $\beta-\alpha$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Subtraction on the right is not always possible (i.e., there exist ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha\geq\beta$ and that, for no ordinal $\gamma$, we have $\gamma+\beta=\alpha$).  An example is when $\alpha=\omega$ and $\beta=1$.  The uniqueness doesn't hold either (e.g., $1+\omega=\omega=0+\omega$).

Subtraction on the left is, however, always possible (i.e., for every ordinals $\alpha,\beta$ such that $\alpha\geq\beta$, there exists a unique ordinal $\gamma$ such that $\beta+\gamma=\alpha$).  This can be proven by transfinite induction (use Bernard's hint to show the existence of $\gamma$; for the uniqueness part, show by induction on the ordinal $y$ that, if $x,z$ are ordinals such that $x<y$, then $z+x<z+y$, which then implies that ordinal addition is left-cancellative, namely, for an ordinal $\gamma'$, if $\beta+\gamma=\beta+\gamma'$, then $\gamma=\gamma'$).

Comment: Why is it called _"Subtraction on the left"_ or _"left-subtraction"_ (and respectively with _right_) and how would they look when using the $\alpha-\beta=\gamma$ subtraction operator in each case?

Comment: @AdiShavit It simply means the result of the subtraction is added on the left side i.e. $\alpha-\beta=\gamma\iff\alpha=\gamma+\beta$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt your definition of subtraction on the left does not match the one given in the answer, which uses $\alpha = \beta + \gamma$ instead.

Answer (score 5):

A *left* subtraction is always possible: let $\gamma$ be the unique ordinal isomorphic to the well-ordered set
$$\bigl\{\xi\mid \alpha\le\xi<\beta\bigr\}.$$
One can show $\,\alpha+\gamma=\beta$.

Comment: I allready suggested that in a comment. What still lacks is a proof of what "one can show".

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Say $\alpha  + 1= \beta$. Then for $\alpha + \gamma$ to be equal to $\beta$, $\gamma$ must be $1$. But if $\alpha$ is infinite, then $1+\alpha = \alpha \neq \beta$.

That being said, we do have the notion of $\alpha - 1$, which is usually defined as
$$
\alpha - 1 = \cases{\text{undefined (or $0$)} & if $\alpha = 0$\\\alpha & if $\alpha$ is limit ordinal\\ \beta & if $\alpha = \beta + 1$}
$$

Comment: As an ordinal, $\alpha+1=\alpha\cup\{\alpha\}\neq\alpha$ (indeed $\alpha+1>\alpha$).

Comment: Actually you proved that addition is not commutative. If $\alpha<\beta$ and $\gamma$ is the type of the wellordening on $\beta-\alpha$ don't we have $\alpha+\gamma=\beta$ then? I am not familiar enough with this stuff to make a statement of that.

Comment: Also, if $\alpha$  is a limit ordinal it is false that $\alpha-1=\alpha$.

Comment: @Bernard we are dealing here with a definion of $\alpha-1$. How could that be false?

Comment: We should have $(\alpha-1)+1=\alpha$, shouldn't we?

Comment: @Bernard In that case, what do _you_ suggest $\omega - 1$ is so that $(\omega - 1) + 1 = \omega$? I know you would like that to be true, but it just can't be done for limit ordinals. The definition in my answer is the second-best thing.

Comment: When using the $0-1=0$ form of the definition, it can be stated directly as set operation on von-Neumann ordinals: $\alpha-1 = \bigcup \alpha$

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, note that you can construct the [Grothendieck group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group) of the ordinals under [Hessenberg arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations), (which is commutative), just as one constructs the integers from the natural numbers under the latter’s arithmetic. This allows you to define subtraction in the usual way. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3284679/a-complete-ordered-field-of-ordinals) for an example.

Alternatively, you can define a truncated subtraction, or [monus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monus), on the ordinals themselves, provided you use the Hessenberg sum (which again is commutative).