# Hessenberg power of ordinals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals, well-orders

According to [these notes](https://jalexstark.com/notes/OrdinalArithmetic.pdf) on ordinal arithmetic:

- The Hessenberg sum $\alpha + \beta$ is the supremum of ordinals that are isomorphic to some well-order on $\alpha \sqcup \beta = (\{0\} \times \alpha) \cup (\{1\} \times \beta)$ extending the union partial-order:
  $$x \leq y \Longleftrightarrow (x_1 = y_1) \land (x_2 \leq y_2)$$
- The Hessenberg product $\alpha \times \beta$ is the supremum of ordinals that are isomorphic to some well-order on $\alpha \times \beta$ extending the product partial-order:
  $$x \leq y \Longleftrightarrow (x_1 \leq y_1) \land (x_2 \leq y_2)$$

Does it make sense to define the Hessenberg power $\alpha^\beta$ as the supremum of ordinals that are isomorphic to some well-order on $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$ extending the following partial-order?
$$x \leq y \Longleftrightarrow \forall z \in \beta: x(z) \leq y(z)$$

If so, does it satisfy the following properties?

1. $\alpha^{\beta + \gamma} = \alpha^\beta \times \alpha^\gamma$
2. $\alpha^{\beta \times \gamma} = (\alpha^\beta)^\gamma$

And what would be, for example, $2^\omega$, $3^\omega$, and $\omega^\omega$?

Comment: There may be some way to define a commutative exponentiation but I doubt it would behave well. The problem with this one is that any well-founded order on a set extends to a well-order. Any such well-order on say $2^{\omega}$ must be larger than $2^{\aleph_0}$, which I suppose is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @nombre Sorry, what do you mean by a commutative exponentiation?

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part: I mean with $\alpha^{\beta \gamma}=\alpha^{\gamma \beta}$ (I tend to think of Hessenberg operations as "commutative versions of ordinal operations", although this is misleading).

Comment: @nombre Ah, but isn't $\beta \gamma = \gamma \beta$ always true (in Hessenberg arithmetic)?

Comment: Hehe, indeed it is, I guess I don't even know what I meant!

Comment: (following celtschk's answer): indeed your partial order is not well-founded so what I said doesn't even apply. One way to correct this would be to consider, instead of $\alpha^{\beta}$, the set ${\alpha}^{(\beta)}$ of functions $\beta \rightarrow \alpha$ taking only finitely many times a non-zero value. This is the base set for one standard definition of the ordinal exponentiation $\alpha^{\beta}$.

Comment: @nombre So $\alpha \uparrow_\text{Hessenberg} \beta$ is the supremum of ordinals that are order-isomorphic to some well-order on $\alpha^{(\beta)}$ extending $f \leq g \Longleftrightarrow \forall x \in \beta: f(x) \leq g(x)$?

Comment: Yes, or at least this seems to be a more relevant definition. You could try to compute $2 \uparrow_{Hessenberg} \omega$ and $4 \uparrow_{Hessenberg} \omega$ and see if the latter is the Hessenberg square of the former.

Comment: @nombre I think you meant whether $(\omega \uparrow_H 2) \uparrow_H 2 = (\omega \uparrow_H 2) \times_H (\omega \uparrow_H 2) = \omega \uparrow_H 4$, right?

Comment: Yes or that indeed. But I expected you wanted the exponentiation to behave well with respect to Hessenberg product as well.

Comment: @nombre I think the ordered semiring $(\mathbb{N}[X], \preceq, +, \cdot)$ of natural-coefficient polynomials is isomorphic to $(\omega^\omega, \subseteq, +_H, \cdot_H)$, where $f \preceq g \leftrightarrow \forall x \exists y (x \leq y \rightarrow f(y) \leq g(y))$ is the dominance order. I expect we'd want the Hessenberg power $\uparrow_H$ to accord with ordinary exponentiation $\uparrow$ of functions.

Comment: @nombre More precisely, let $f : \varepsilon_0 \rightarrow (\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N})$ where
\begin{align}
    f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \omega^{\beta_i} c_i\right)
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{N}^{f(\beta_i)} c_i
\end{align}
where the argument to $f$ is in Cantor normal form. Let
\begin{align}
    \alpha \uparrow \beta = f^{-1}(f(\alpha)^{f(\beta)})
\end{align}
This seems to be the natural candidate for Hessenberg exponentiation. Does it have an order-theoretic definition, like the natural sum and product?

Comment: @nombre Posted a question about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711862/hessenberg-power-of-ordinals-redux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction cannot work.

Consider the case $2^\omega$. The functions in that case would be the characteristic functions of subsets of $\omega$, and the partial order you give then simply refers to the subset order of the corresponding sets.

Now consider the set $M=\{\omega\setminus n\mid n\in\omega\}$. The elements of this set have the form $S_n=\omega\setminus n=\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,\ldots\}$. Now it is easily seen that the inclusion partial order already gives a total order on $S_n$, namely $S_m\subseteq S_n\iff m\ge n$.

Note the reversal of the order direction here, which means that because $\omega$ has no maximal element, $V$ has no minimal element. And since $V$ is already totally ordered, no extension of the partial order on $2^\omega$ will cause its order to change.

Therefore no extension of that partial order on $2^\omega$ to a well-order can exist, which means your exponentiation function is not defined for $2^\omega$.

Comment: Posted a follow-up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711862/hessenberg-power-of-ordinals-redux).